# Does hash_map.erase invalidate all iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, hashmap

`std::hash_map` is not part of the `C++ standard` but is part of extensions to standard library. For example it is defined for [VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x7w9f6z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Would normally `std::hash_map.erase` invalidate all iterators to `std::hash_map`? Presumably, the memory can be reallocated to a smaller array when elements are removed to optimize for memory usage.

So does `hash_map.erase` actually invalidate all iterators?

Comment: It's doubtful that erasing elements would trigger a release of memory used by the hash bucket array itself as resizing is typically pretty expensive. You'll need to check your particular compiler's doco or code, or from the VS2005 link Leonid posted you can find a bucket_count() function documented - just insert a million entries in a hash then erase them and check the bucket_count before/after the erase....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is specified in [VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398039.aspx) example in the documentation:

> Each element contains a separate key and a mapped value. The sequence is represented in a way that permits lookup, insertion, and removal of an arbitrary element with a number of operations that is independent of the number of elements in the sequence (constant time) -- at least in the best of cases. Moreover, inserting an element invalidates no iterators, and **removing** an element invalidates only those iterators which point at the removed element.